# if - else if statement with falsy value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var x = 0; 
if (!true) 
{ 
    x = 1; 
} 
else if (false) 
{ 
    x = 2; 
}
else {
    x = 3; 
} 
alert(x);
```

var x has 0, which is a falsy value so, condition is false. Then why if (!true) does not execute and else statement executes?

Comment: The `(!true)` part is a self contained expression that evaluates to `false`. It has nothing to do with `var x=0`. You most likely want `if (!x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `if(!true)` and `if(false)` aren't valid in your scope.
if the condition equation is false, that section will be skipped.
That is `if(!true)` and `if(false)` aren't valid in your code.

For example, if you want to make `infinite loop`,

You may use `while(true)` or `while(1)`, you may not use `while(false)` or `while(0)`.

Because `while` and `if` check if the content of equation is `true`

Answer (score 0):

First, indent the code

```
var x = 0;

if (!true){ 
    x = 1;
} 
else if (false){ 
    x = 2; 
}
else {
    x = 3; 
} 
alert(x);
```

!true = false

Doesn't matter the x value, this will always be false